# Google App Engine Logs "The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.1' was not found."

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, asp.net-core-3.1

When running my .net core 3.1 service on google app engine flexible, i receive a series of errors periodically which occurs ostensibly independent of service invocation:

- "The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.1' was not found."
- The following frameworks were found:
- 3.0.1 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

These errors are logged about every 3-4 minutes - whether the service is invoked or not.

Development and Runtime:

- Visual Studio 2019 on Windows with 1 webapi service project (/api/values) and a docker-compose project
- .Net Core 3.1
- Docker linux container
- Google App Engine Flexible

I have read several articles about this type of error, but in my case i do not have any 2.1.1 references or code. I am targeting .net core 3.1. How do i resolve?

The errors do not occur when i "dotnet run" or "docker run" locally. They only appear in the GAE environment. Does GAE have a dependency on 2.1.1? or is 3.1.1 not "supported"

I have tried targeting multipe frameworks but this creates all kinds of reference problems in the application. In any event, the service functions correctly. On the other hand, colleagues reviewing the error log will use it as a scape goat for any and all problems ever related to the service.

So is the problem in the solution, the dockerfile, or GAE?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
# EXPOSE 80
# EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 8080
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
ADD dev-certificate.pfx /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/dev-certificate.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
COPY Xxxxx.Orchestrations.Cost/Xxxxx.Orchestrations.Cost.csproj Xxxxx.Orchestrations.Cost/
RUN dotnet restore "Xxxxx.Orchestrations.Cost/Xxxxx.Orchestrations.Cost.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Xxxx.Orchestrations.Cost"
RUN dotnet build "Xxxxx.Orchestrations.Cost.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Xxxxx.Orchestrations.Cost.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
# CMD chmod /app/publish/dev-certificate.pfx +rrr


# ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080;https://*:443
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=dev-certificate.pfx
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=ufo
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Xxxxx.Orchestrations.Cost.dll"]
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex


# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

network:
    name: default
    subnetwork_name: default-us-east1

service: get-cost

env_variables:
  # The __ in My__Greeting will be translated to a : by ASP.NET.
  My__Greeting: Hello AppEngine Flex!
```

Comment: Have you [specified](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/runtime#extending_the_runtime) the `runtime: custom` line in your app.yaml?

Comment: i had forgotten to change it back to custom after experimentation, but i still get the errors after returning it to custom as shown above in the code i added to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending culprit in this scenario was a line of boiler plate VS code for the StartUp class in the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```

changing the code to

```
services.AddMvc();
```

eliminated the error message in the google app engine logs.